# Is it possible to show separate tool-tip with text for candlestick feed (high,low,open,close) value in Plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have a problem when I want to display **candlestick hoverinfo in separate tool-tip**.

I want to show hoverinfo(high,low,open,close) with separated tool-tip like the image bellow.

[image]

But as far as I know plotly js support candlestick hoverinfo(high,low,open,close) in one tool-tip.

Ex:
[image]

Is there any way?

Thanks in advance.